# How to access Facebook Developer Operations Team at utl-devops@fb.com

Tags: facebook

The problem is that I received a notification that a request for information has been sent to my email, but I recently updated the contact email address for my app and I am unable to access it, and I need to receive the same email again, this time on my new contact email address.

I tried to reach out to the Facebook Developer Operations Team at utl-devops@fb.com. But get the following message:

> l;dr emailing devops@ will no longer generate a task. Look to the channels below for your devops@ inquiries.

Can anyone suggest a functional method or email to contact the Facebook Developer Operations Team?